# Home route in ui-router

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I use https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router library. When I try to access index route ('/') I'm redirected to 404. The code:

```
angular.module('cr').config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
    $stateProvider
        .state('home', {
            url: '/',
            templateUrl: 'views/index.html'
        });

    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/404');
});
```

What's wrong with that code? Although when I use ui-sref="home" it works but the url looks like '/#/' but when a user inputs site name he uses just domain name, like 'mysite.com', not 'mysite.com/#/'

Answer (score 34, accepted):

You've declared how to behave when any *unknown/other* route is provided - go to `/404`.

But we also have to define how to behave, when some expected, but not "exact" / "not known" route is accessed, ie. create **alias**

That's where the `.when()` could/should be used:

```
...

// the known route, with missing '/' - let's create alias
$urlRouterProvider.when('', '/');

// the unknown
$urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/404');
```

Comment: Solved exactly the issue I was having today!

Comment: For anyone else who uses `$urlMatcherFactoryProvider.strictMode(false)`, for optional trailing slashes, `$urlRouterProvider.when('', '/')` will cause the default route to fail altogether. Instead, I check for an empty $location.url() within my otherwise function, and redirect to the default state. See here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/40669255/490592

Answer (score 7):

There is nothing wrong with your code. You are just missing an explicit state for 404. Try adding this:

```
.state('404', {
    url: '{path:.*}',
    templateUrl: 'views/404'
});
```

To get rid of the hash (#) symbol you need to inject one more dependency into your config module:

```
$locationProvider
```

And use the .html5Mode() method to set HTML5 Mode to true, like so

```
$locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
```

Also, ensure your server is configured to allow Angular to handle your routing. For example, here is a Node/Express configuration that allows the above technique to work:

```
app.get('*', routes.index);
```

And in your index.js file (or however you configure your node.js instance):

```
exports.index = function(req, res){
   res.render('index');
};
```

Answer (score 2):

Here by example:

```
// the known route, with missing '/' - let's create alias
$urlRouterProvider.when('', '/');

// Redirect any unmatched url to 404 view (without change location.hash)
$urlRouterProvider.otherwise(function($injector) {
    var $state = $injector.get('$state');
    $state.go('404', null, {
        location: false
    });

}); 

$stateProvider
    // homepage views
    .state('homepage', {
        url: "/",
        templateUrl: "views/homepage.html",            
        data: {
            pageTitle: 'Home'
        }
        ... more here ...
    })
    // 404 views
    .state('404', {
        url: "/404",
        templateUrl: "views/404.html",            
        data: {
            pageTitle: '404 Not found'
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way for me with ui-router was giving the url field an empty value :

```
        $stateProvider
        .state('home', {
            url: '',
            templateUrl: 'views/homepage.html',
            controller: 'AppCtrl'
        })
```