# Angular UI-Router sending root url to 404

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I am having an infuriating issue regarding `ui-router`. Everything works as I want, where all bad URLs are sent to the `404` state. However, even though my default state is correctly rendered when the url is `/#/`, the url of `/` is redirected to `/404/`. How can I server the `default` state to both `/` and `/#/`?

**app.js**

```
MyApp.config( function ($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {

// For any unmatched url, send to 404
$urlRouterProvider.otherwise("/404/");

$stateProvider
    // Home  (default)
    .state('default', {
        url: '/',
        resolve: {
            ...
        },
   }
});
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I think this will accomplish your needs -

```
MyApp.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
    // the known route
    $urlRouterProvider.when('', '/');

    // For any unmatched url, send to 404
    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/404');

    $stateProvider
        // Home  (default)
        .state('default', {
            url: '/',
            resolve: {
                // ...
            }
            // ....
        });
});
```

I refered to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20885365/home-route-in-ui-router?rq=1).  You may need to use a regular expression to handle routes with data.

Instead of the  `#` in your URL you can use a query string too and grab it via `$stateParams` in a state.

Here is how you can do that -

```
  // ....

  $stateProvider

    .state('default', {
        url: '/?data',
        templateUrl: 'templates/index.html',
        controller: 'defaultCtrl'
    })
```

And then you can use this below to go to home with data -

```
var toStateData = {
    key1: 'value1',
    key2: 'value2'
}

$state.go('default', {data: JSON.stringify(toStateData)});
```

You don't have to stringify the data in `$stateParams` but this will allow more options with one parameter.  In the `defaultCtrl` controller you can get the passed query string like this -

```
var stateData = JSON.parse($stateParams.data);
var key1 = stateData.key1;
// ....
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for taking me in the right direction - didn't realise that  `.when` provides an alias. However, my use case is actually the reverse you have posted. When the base `/` url is found, I need it to alias to `/#/` (`''` and `'/'` in the state router). If you adjust your answer, I'll happily accept ;)

Comment: This what I added: `$urlRouterProvider.when('', '/');`

Answer (score 2):

I wanted to do this only with states, so no url provider involved. I found the following solution which I think is good:

(sorry it's coffeescript)

```
  $stateProvider.
    state('base.public.notFound',
      url:         '^*path'
      templateUrl: 'views/layouts/404.html'
    )
```

Put this as the last state and you are done!

Comment: I would like to note, that for whatever reason, this did not work for me.

Comment: I don't know your code, but with this one, you should not use the `.otherwise` or such, only stateprovider.