# How can redirect to 404 page in Angular ui router

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

Hi I am getting problem while implementing 404 page using angular ui router'
Scenario
when the user type something in the url which was not present in the app i have to show 404 page not found page

What I tried

app.js

```
var myapp = angular.module('myapp', ['ui.router']);

myapp.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {

    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/xxx/xxxoverview');

    $stateProvider.state('xxx', {
        url:'/xxx',
        templateUrl :'partials/xxx/xxxOverview.html',
        controller:'xxxAccordionCtrl'
    })
     .state('404', {
        url:'/404',
        templateUrl :'404.html'

    });
```

My Actual Design

[image]

I am getting the following response
[image]

I am expecting

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to get what you are expecting you need to write your layout better.

You layout is currently:

```
 <div>
     .. some layout code here 
     <div> navigation here </div>
     <div ui-view></div>
     ..some more layout
 </div>
```

in order to get the result you want you have use nested ui-views

```
 <div>
       .. outer layout
       <div ui-view> 
             .. inner layout
             <div> navigation here </div>
             <div ui-view></div>
             .. inner layout cont. 
       </div>
        .. outer layout cont. 
</div>
```

and change the routing accordingly.

if you give me a couple of minutes I will prepare a plunkr for you.

So this is a plunker for you: 
http://plnkr.co/edit/Y6PqRhrbvpEpWApm9lkS?p=preview

and this is the breakdown of the code I did

```
$stateProvider
     .state('layout', {
       template: 'my navigation <div ui-view></div>'

     } )
     .state('layout.page', {
       url: '/page',
       template: 'this is my content go see a missing page <a href="#/404">missing page link</a>'
     })
     .state('404', {
       url:'/404',
       template: '404!!! page is missing'
     });
```

As you can see I have an "abstract" state called "layout", which basically defines template but that's it! no url, no controller no nothing.

I add the navigation in the template, and then another ui-view. - NOTE I already have a ui-view on my `index.html`. other than that that `index.html` can be empty as far as I care. I added `hello` there just so you have a point of reference.

then my page is a nested state inside layout. see state `layout.page`. This is what is so great in angular-ui-router. 
This way you can have different layouts for different sections of the website. 
So my page uses the layout simply by nesting the state.

then I have a different state which I called 404. 
Since it does not inherit from layout, it will not have the navigation.

Comment: @RavindharKonka - added plunker + explanation. if you have any question please let me know.

Comment: I have gone through the plunker 
But how can I valid the  url  .In the plunker u gave link to navigate 404 page But if the user enter invalid user then i want 404 page can you please help me

Comment: @RavindharKonka - that is a different problem and you can find the solution at:: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23438664/angular-ui-router-sending-root-url-to-404

Comment: thanks @guy mograbi you are resolve my problem and I supported (UpVote) this answer :)

Comment: @RavindharKonka please consider marking my answer as the solution (press the check mark) so it will not appear as "open" in the search.

Answer (score 1):

Have you your index.html like this?

```
<nav>You navigation</nav>
<ui-view> </ui-view>
```

You can put your `<nav>You navigation</nav>` in `templateUrl :'partials/xxx/xxxOverview.html'`